# Webcomic following a boy who's inhabited by a vengeful ghost who's after the men who killed her

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I think that I read this in the late 90s to the early 2000s. It might have been on Keenspot at the time, as I read a lot of comics there. More of a western art-style, not anime, more realistic than cartoony, in English, full-page entries with panels. The protagonist was a Caucasian male teenager, I want to say with light brown hair. Early in the comic, he's possessed by the girl (her body replacing his), who might be either a witch or a vampire. I remember he was initially topless, so she somehow used his briefs to improvise a halter-top (she was busty and I remember it kind of stretched credulity for me), which led to his mother commenting the next day, I think "off-camera", asking how he'd stretched them out so much. He has no memories of the night, but I think she sucked out life energy from a guy she picked up in a bar.

We learn that, before the initial events of the comic, she was killed and buried by a group of men, then much younger. I don't remember if they killed her because they thought she was evil, or if it was something more malicious or accidental, but they've kept it a secret ever since. One of them is now a town official. One is a mortician (he's creepy and I think it's either implied or outright stated that he did something sexual to the girl either before or after her death). And the third is a long-haired priest, or minister, who's the uncle of the protagonist. Over the course of that first possession, I think she killed off another member of their group, so they meet to discuss what to do now that she's back.

Past that, I don't remember much, and I think that the comic stalled out... pretty sure that the girl confronted the priest at some point, and later on, she and the boy were able to talk to one another in their shared body. I think the title of either the comic or the site might have had something to do with an 8-ball... or maybe that was in their logo.

I remember the artwork as being in color at least some of the time, and it was non-realistic, but also not cartoony. People had normal proportions.

I have a vague memory of another comic (determined by frog42 to be Eight's [*Road Waffles*](http://www.roadwaffles.com/), running on Keenspot from 1999-2004 along with two other comics, the site being named "Eightland") being related, maybe sharing a writer and/or artist, but all I remember about that comic was that one part had a ninja girl with a smiley-face mask car-surfing the protagonist's vehicle, and responding to them slamming the brakes by leaning impossibly far forward to avoid being thrown off, and a later arc where two boys pick up a female hitchhiker and, while they're at a gas station, one of the boys tries to force her to expose her breasts or they'll ditch her there (he might have used the Internet phrase of "Tits or GTFO"), leading to the other boy punching the first boy and apologizing to the girl. I'm not 100% that this comic is tied to it, but any small possible corroborating detail, right?

I contacted Eight and got the following response:

> Nope, doesn't ring a bell.. so I'm not the artist.

Comment: It sounds a lot like an early installment of [Wapsi Square,](http://wapsisquare.com/) possibly memory-crossed with some other webcomic. All the main characters in Wapsi Square are women, but posession (by the personifications of one's "personal demons") is a common theme. The main character in the early installments is an improbably busty woman named Monica, who often wears an [8-ball teeshirt.](http://wapsisquare.com/comic/01252002/)

Comment: I should mention that Wapsi Square is mildly NSFW.

Comment: I am familiar with Wapsi Square and that is not the correct one, although that is a good guess. Maybe that's where I'm remembering the 8-ball from... anyhow, since that's a point of reference, the artwork was color, I think, and less sketchy than Wapsi Square, even the later installments, less cartoony body proportions.

Comment: Grrr... this one is bugging the heck out of me.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I went through some random index pages on keenspot at archive.org, for various months/years and I didn't see anything that looked like it would fit.

Comment: @JohnP Which makes me wonder if maybe it was a Keenspace one, or entirely independent, which will makes this all the more difficult.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Possibly Joe Cartoon? He did a few serial comics.

Comment: @JohnP: I doubt it. It wasn't that cartoony. It wasn't photorealistic, and there were some exaggerated features, but not cartoonishly so, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Well that at least narrows the pool. Still wading around some dark corners, I'll see what turns up.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Road Waffles](http://www.roadwaffles.com/).

It ran from 1999-2005 on keenspot.com, with a fourth volume released in 2011.

Comment: Hi there! Instead of writing "more crap", maybe you could [edit] in a summary, or some panes which match what Fuzzy described? This would make for a better answer :)

Comment: What other users have said, there is a character limit for a reason and it should have hinted at you to explain how this matches the OP’s description. You can [edit] in why this matches though, please do so!

Comment: That may be the second one that I remembered as being contemporary. The name sounds familiar, and the art looks familiar. Unfortunately, it's not the one that I'm looking for as the primary answer.